# how can get variable from config file in CodeIgniter i need in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I have this code in config file:

```php
if (isset($_GET['language']))
{
    $language = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['language'], '._-', 'ABCDlanguage48+/='));
    $_SESSION["language"] = $language;
    $config['language'] = $language;
}
```

And I need `$language` in controller `__construct` function. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added given code in my `application/config/config.php` (End of file)

In my `Controller` have added code in `Construct` function like this:

```
$this->data = $this->config->item('language');
```

And now I can use it in any function of my `Controller`.

like: `echo $this->data;`